# Why document.getelementbyid().value does not work for me when input is text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't know why document.getelementbyid().value does not work for me.

After checking the console, I can not see any input was sent or print out in console.

```js
function makeApiCall() {
  var keyword = document.getElementById('user_input').value;
  console.log(document.getElementById('user_input').value);
  var url = 'someURL' + keyword + 'someURL';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json"
  }).then(function(photos) {
    console.log(photos)
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  makeApiCall();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_input" placeholder="Please enter the keyword">
</div>
<div class="col">
  <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="makeApiCall()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When do you call that javascript code?

Comment: If it doesn't print anything _at all_, then the `console.log` is most like not called at all.

Comment: You have to execute the code when something is entered in the field

Comment: any error display show on your console?

Comment: If you add `value="nothing yet"` to your field, the snippet I made for you WILL show that in the console

Comment: Some people do manipulate to vote down another developer answer

Comment: See my update to your question. If your code is written as above, it works - I had to add a `)`to `.then(function(photos) {
    ...
  })`

Comment: The makeApiCall in the ready, will not work unless you prefill the user_input

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function() {` to `$("#user_input").change(makeApiCall)`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an *empty* value because you are trying to get the value of the input once and just after the JavaScript is loaded. Therefore it is empty.

You need to add an event listener to the input element which listens `input` event in order to get the value of it.

```js
var keyword = document.getElementById('user_input')

function makeApiCall() {
  var keywordValue = keyword.value;
  var url = 'someURL' + keywordValue + 'someURL';
  
  console.log(url)
  
  /*
  ...
  The AJAX Stuff
  ...
  */
}

keyword.addEventListener('input', makeApiCall)
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_input" placeholder="Please enter the keyword">
</div>
```

But since you're using jQuery, you can refactor it as followings:

```js
var keyword = $('#user_input')

function makeApiCall() {
  var keywordValue = keyword.val();
  var url = 'someURL' + keywordValue + 'someURL';
  
  console.log(url)
  
  /*
  ...
  The AJAX Stuff
  ...
  */
}

keyword.on('input', makeApiCall)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_input" placeholder="Please enter the keyword">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but the code i put on the page is already in the function makeApiCall. So what should I do?

Comment: @MIKUVOCALOID You have no mentioning of makeApiCall in the question. Please update the snippet to a [mcve]

Comment: Just to note: the question was changed substantially after this answer (and the above) comments were provided.

Comment: @MIKUVOCALOID I updated the answer as your request.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
By the default, the button in HTML using submit rather than button type. I need add a type = 'button'. After that, it work!
If the type is submit, it will do the submit process rather than my function. So the type should be button.